# Image of a convergent sequence in an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose I have a function $f:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ that is increasing on its domain and a sequence $a_n \subset [a,b)$ such that $a_n \to b$ and $f(a_n)\to l\in \mathbb{R}$.

How would I go about showing that $l=sup(im \ f)$?

Any hints would be well appreciated, not full answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in [a,b)$ be arbitrary. We can always pick $N$ s.t. $n > N \implies a_n \in (x_0,b) \implies f(a_n) \geq f(x_0)$.

Comment: It would seem that I need to think about it much more than this because I still don't know where to go from this point either, but thank you for the hint!

Comment: One more hint: From what I said in my answer, you can deduce that $l$ must be greater than $f(x_0)$ for any $x_0 \in [a,b)$.

Comment: I see that that makes $l$ an upperbound. Now I just need to show it is the least such, or use some other equivalent definition for supremum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in [a,b)$, you have $a_n$ such that $x< a_n$, and hence $f(x) \le f(a_n) \le l$.